# Layout of app destroyed while recycling the recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an android app in which i'm using `RecyclerView`.

In `RecyclerView`'s itens I'm using one `TextView` and four `CheckBox`es for selection anyone.

Now when I select one `CheckBox` others become disable according to the code that I've written. Now the problem is that when i recycle the `RecyclerView` after selection of CheckBoxes the other become disable without any selection.

The same happens when I select the CheckBoxes from the bottom of the RecyclerView the upper CheckBoxes also become disabled.

I wish to solve this problem.

Here is my code in adapter class.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Food foodItems = foodList.get(position);
    holder.txtPersonName.setText(foodItems.getPersonNames());
    holder.chkSavour.setChecked(foodItems.getChkSavour());
    holder.chkBurgur.setChecked(foodItems.getChkBurgur());
    holder.chkKrrahi.setChecked(foodItems.getChkKrrahi());

    holder.chkSavour.setTag(position);
    holder.chkSavour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer pos = (Integer) holder.chkSavour.getTag();
            if (!foodList.get(pos).getChkSavour()){
                foodList.get(pos).setChkSavour(true);
                holder.chkKrrahi.setEnabled(false);
                holder.chkBurgur.setEnabled(false);
                holder.chkNone.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                foodList.get(pos).setChkSavour(false);
                holder.chkBurgur.setEnabled(true);
                holder.chkKrrahi.setEnabled(true);
                holder.chkNone.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
    holder.chkBurgur.setTag(position);
    holder.chkBurgur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer pos = (Integer) holder.chkBurgur.getTag();
            if (!foodList.get(pos).getChkBurgur()){
                foodList.get(pos).setChkBurgur(true);
                holder.chkSavour.setEnabled(false);
                holder.chkKrrahi.setEnabled(false);
                holder.chkNone.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                foodList.get(pos).setChkBurgur(false);
                holder.chkSavour.setEnabled(true);
                holder.chkKrrahi.setEnabled(true);
                holder.chkNone.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
    holder.chkKrrahi.setTag(position);
    holder.chkKrrahi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer pos = (Integer) holder.chkKrrahi.getTag();
            if (!foodList.get(pos).getChkKrrahi()){
                foodList.get(pos).setChkKrrahi(true);
                holder.chkSavour.setEnabled(false);
                holder.chkBurgur.setEnabled(false);
                holder.chkNone.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                foodList.get(pos).setChkKrrahi(false);
                holder.chkSavour.setEnabled(true);
                holder.chkBurgur.setEnabled(true);
                holder.chkNone.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView txtPersonName;
        private CheckBox chkSavour;
        private CheckBox chkBurgur;
        private CheckBox chkKrrahi;
        private CheckBox chkNone;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtPersonName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            chkSavour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkSavour);
            chkBurgur = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkBurgur);
            chkKrrahi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkKrrahi);
            chkNone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkNone);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try storing previous selections in a list and then make those selection with loop on that list before current item gets selected

Comment: Hey....! can you justify your answer please.... 
How it could be done? 
Kindly write the code with justification plzz.

Comment: I can't write code for you but i can guide you in doing so

Comment: Ok.... Guide me.....

Answer (score 0):

You missed View Enabling/Disabling part. Add following lines after you set your checkboxes check status.

```
holder.chkSavour.setChecked(foodItems.getChkSavour());
holder.chkBurgur.setChecked(foodItems.getChkBurgur());
holder.chkKrrahi.setChecked(foodItems.getChkKrrahi());

//Add this
if(foodItems.isSelected()){
    holder.chkSavour.setEnabled(foodItems.getChkSavour())
    holder.chkKrrahi.setEnabled(foodItems.getChkKrrahi());
    holder.chkBurgur.setEnabled(foodItems.getChkBurgur());
    holder.chkNone.setEnabled(foodItems.getChkNone());
}else{
    holder.chkSavour.setEnabled(true)
    holder.chkKrrahi.setEnabled(true);
    holder.chkBurgur.setEnabled(true);
    holder.chkNone.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Add a boolean variable in your model to hold status of user preference has been selected or not.

```
holder.chkSavour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer pos = (Integer) holder.chkSavour.getTag();
        if (!foodList.get(pos).getChkSavour()){
            foodList.get(pos).setChkSavour(true);
            foodList.get(pos).setSelected(true); //Used to apply view Enable logic
            holder.chkKrrahi.setEnabled(false);
            holder.chkBurgur.setEnabled(false);
            holder.chkNone.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            foodList.get(pos).setChkSavour(false);
            foodList.get(pos).setSelected(false); //Reset the disabled check box
            holder.chkBurgur.setEnabled(true);
            holder.chkKrrahi.setEnabled(true);
            holder.chkNone.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey....! Here's a funny seen created by adding these lines that every checkbox become disabled on app running first time.

Comment: Okkkey. But here's also a problem...! 
When i scrolled out the recyclerview items that become disable by selecting the checkboxes become enable again....

Comment: Did you add additional variable in your model to hold selection status? Like `private boolean foodSelectionStatus = false` and access it use getter and setter `foodItems.isSelected()` and `foodList.get(pos).setSelected(true);` repectively.